# Hopcroft–Karp Algorithm for a dynamic graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matching-theory, perfect-matchings

As so you all know, we have Hopcroft–Karp Algorithm for maximum matching between two sides in a bipartite graph. It runs in $O(\sqrt{V} \times E)$ where $V$ is the vertex set and $E$ is the edges set.

I am looking for an algorithm that will fit more efficiently for a dynamic graph.

At each iteration `i`, for graph `G` in that iteration (Denote `G_i`) I'm adding one node maximum for each side, and connecting some edges between the existing nodes and the new nodes that are being added. This will be graph `G_(i+1)`.

***The Question:***

Given a maximum matching in `G_i` can I efficiently calculate maximum matching in `G_(i+1)` (and avoid running Hopcroft–Karp Algorithm every time)?

***What I have tried:***

For starters, the matching in `G_(i+1)` can only increase by one since I am adding at most one node to each side. If some edge connects to some node that is not in the matching, I just add both nodes to the matching of `G_(i+1)`, Otherwise, I am trying to do what we did in Hopcroft–Karp Algorithm, Finding an augmenting path.

An augmenting path is a simple path that starts with a node `v` that doesn't appear in the matching and ends with node `u` that is on the opposite side of `v`. The path itself is alternating between an edge in the matching and an edge not in the matching.

[Illustration of augmenting path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ihrx.png)

Comment: If there is a larger matching it uses an edge incident with a new vertex, so you just need to look for an augmenting path starting with such an edge.

Comment: Thank you very much